# Why does Java not impose a restriction to have the child class visibility greater than the parent class

Tags: java, polymorphism, package, public, overriding

Why can you create a child class in Java whose visibility is less than the super class.

```
package 1
public class Class1 {

    public Class1 hello(){
        Class1 c= new Class2();
        return c;
    }   
}


class Class2 extends Class1 {

     public Class1 hello() {
        System.out.println("In overriden method");
            return null;
    }    
}
```

Say both Class1 and Class2 are in the same package , Class2 visibility is package private.

```
package 2
public class Major {
    public static  void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 ob = new Class1();
        ob.hello().hello();
    }
}
```

You will notice that the "In overriden method" will be printed because of runtime polymorphism.

During runtime how can `hello()` method of `Class2` be accessed from `main()` when `Class2` is in a different package with package-private visibility ?

`Class2` should not be accessible and as such the `hello(`) method in `Class2` should also not be accessible.

Comment: There is nothing preventing public classes from package 2 returning instances of Class2.

Comment: Don't use quotations but `code-blocks` (button with `{}` icon in editors menu) to preserve formatting.

Comment: Why would you want to force such a restriction? It doesnt make sense

Comment: The `main` method cannot access `Class2` directly, because the existence of `Class2` and what it does is an internal matter for package 1. However, with polymorphism, an instance of `Class2` could be handed to `main` as a `Class1` reference, and `main` is allowed to call any public `Class1` method, even if that method is overridden by `Class2`. It's all about [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: `Class2` *isnt* accessible, but anything it implements that is expressed by the contract of `Class1` is, by definition. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your `hello` methods have a return type of `Class1`. That is accessible to `Major`.

Answer (score 0):

The `protected` keyword (somehow similar to package private) is a way to protect your code from being used externally, and this is exactly what happens in your example. You are not using `Class2` directly, you are using `Class1` which grants you the right to use the protected `Class2` indirectly.

This is a responsibility principle. `public Class1` takes the responsibility to grant external packages the usage of `protected Class2`. But this responsibility also means that the developer of `Class1` has to know *why* and *how* he grants you that right.

The fact that you `extend Class1` has no real meaning in your example, and your confusion may come from this. You can't instantiate `Class2` from outside your package, but `Class1` can.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, given the type signatures of the methods involved, it probably couldn't work any other way.

`Class1` declares a method called `hello` returning an object of `Class1`. So, what gets returned from that method *must* implement a compatible interface to `Class1`. When `Class1.hello()` returns an instance of `Class2` there shouldn't be any way in which the caller can interact with it differently than if it was an instance of `Class1` - this is the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in action - one of the key object-oriented principles.

If `Class2.hello()` became innaccessible by virtue of `Class2` being hidden then the caller would have to contend with the fact that they don't know what type of object will be returned by `Class1.hello()` - sometimes it might be an object of `Class2` and sometimes it might be an object of `Class1`, or any other object which could extend from `Class1` and the only way of knowing would be to examine the code - i.e. knowing `Class1`'s implementation details. The compiler wouldn't be able to guarantee type safety in that kind of situation, because `Class1.hello()` could, in principle, be undecidable or dependent on runtime state. In a statically typed language that's pretty much game over.

Making a class hidden in some way - by creating it as a private type, by implementing an interface anonymously, through reflective-trickery, etc - is only supposed to make the type itself hidden and not the interface which it implements. By extending another class any given type automatically inherits the parent type's interface, including its visibility. Extending types are only allowed to increase an interface's visibility, not to decrease it, otherwise the Liskov Substitution Principle is violated.